# What is the best range of numbers to use for ID number relationships in PowerPivot: 1 to 500,000 or 1,000,000 to 1,500,000?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpivot

Using PowerPivot and having a cost table, with 300,000 different costtypes, and a calculation table, with about 700,000 records/types, I change the product strings (which can be quite long) to integers, in order to make them shorter and get the RELATED formula to work faster.

With this many records and cost types, **would it be better to have all the ID numbers the same length of numbers?**

So for example should I start with number 1000000 up to 1500000 or just from 1 to 500000?

Comment: If you used 1 - 500,000 , wouldn't the data files be smaller and therefore more efficient and faster? Shorter numbers would mean that less space is needed to store the number and so easier to parse through.

Comment: It would not matter if numbers are under 2 billion.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving files with 1-500000 and 1000001-1500000 and see the difference in properties. Difference doesn't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

1 to 500,000 is the better option because it is lesser bytes to store. Having the same length has no advantage whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

---

You will *not* notice difference in allocated memory. If you save
`1; 2;...` or `1000001; 1000002;...` or `1 abcdefgh; 2 abcdefgh;...` you will find out that:

2.14 Mb for both  1-64000 and 1000001-1064000 in xls format*
3.02 Mb for 1 abcdefgh; 2 abcdefgh;...
584 Kb on disc (much smaller) for both  1-100000 and 1000001-1100000 in .ods format (you cannot save more). There is a small difference (596069Kb vs 597486Kb, but it is negated by cluster size 4 Kb).

From usability - go for 1,000,000 to 1,500,000. You are guaranteed to have same number of digits. Otherwise it is easy to mess up 1234 vs 11234. Strongly consider SQLite or similar database because 0.5 million of rows is pushing the limits of Excel format.

---

- xls format can store a maximum of 65536 rows and 256 columns

Comment: Half a million is no where near the limit. I have datamodels with more  than 10 million records. With 64 bit Excel 2013, you are limited more by the hardware than by PowerPivot. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Data-Model-specification-and-limits-19AA79F8-E6E8-45A8-9BE2-B58778FD68EF

Comment: Yes, it can handle millions of rows of data. But it gets very slow. Like takes several minutes to load. Besides, if a person is considering 0.5M entries in the beginning his system might grow eventually.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 1000000 take the same amount of space because data is not compressed and space sufficient for an `int` ( number up to 4 billion) is allocated.